# Set AngularJS app configuration from a service

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-services

My app starts with login page as the first view, where user is supposed to enter username and password. Based on the username, properties of the user if fetched from database using `databaseServive`. I want to set angular routing configurations based on the `type` property of the user. If user is of `type` A, following configurations should be set:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider
   .when('/', '/homeA')
   .otherwise('/homeA');

$stateProvider
   .state('tabs', {
       abstract: true,
       url: '/',
       template: '<my-tab-a></my-tab-a>',
       onEnter: function(){console.log("enter");}
   })
});
```

If the user id of `type` B, following configurations should be set:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider
   .when('/', '/homeB')
   .otherwise('/homeB');

$stateProvider
   .state('tabs', {
       abstract: true,
       url: '/',
       template: '<my-tab-b></my-tab-b>',
       onEnter: function(){console.log("enter");}
   })
});
```

How can I set these configurations after allowing user to sign in using initial the login page?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use app.config() once the app is running. So you won't be able to change the routes of the urlRouterProvider.

You have to define all the routes, and in each controller to check if the user is allowed to come (redirect in other case).